# How do I get user information during Java SwingWorker execution?

Tags: java, focus, swingworker

I need to do something like what operating systems do when you drag and drop a lot of files from one folder to another. A progress monitor pops up and displays the progress. If a recoverable error occurs, a new dialog is displayed, asking how to recover, or perhaps to quit.

My problem is that because I have to start the worker thread before I make the progress monitor visible, we may generate an error dialog before the progress monitor comes up. Then when the progress monitor comes up, we have focus problems, since the parentage isn't correct. Sometimes it works, and the error dialog is on top and focused, sometimes, the error dialog is on top but the progress monitor is focussed.

I'm running pretty vanilla code from the ProgressMonitor documentation, calling `setMillisToPopup(0)` and `setMillisToDecideToPopup(0)` before executing the worker.

in the doInBackground() method, I immediately call `setProgress(1)` in a vain attempt to get the progress monitor to show as soon as possible. It frequently works.

If an error occurs, I run `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` to run a `Runnable` to display the dialog and get the result.

In some sense, this is more of a focus problem, but it's created due to the threading.

Any ideas? Am I way off base?

Comment: i dont see any code, i can only make some assumptions over some hypothesis thats not right? is it...

Comment: Probably, because you are running one dialog from `EDT` and another from `worker` thread. Also, updating progress bar outside of EDT is a very bad idea. But please, as Duncan said, try to update your question with sscce.

Comment: I don't think a `ProgressMonitor` is what you need here. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html to use a Progress bar directly, as the time you set for the wait is always 0